# Can't run a meteor project (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu, meteor

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed node.js, npm, nodejs-legacy (via terminal) and I launched the meteor installer from the offical meteor webpage.

Now I have following problem when I try to start my meteor project:

> /home/fabian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_2.354htk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
>         throw error;
>         ^
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/tmp/mt-1jeehae/os.json'
>       at Error (native)

I always get this error message - not only when I try to start my existing project - also when I try to create a new project - always the same message.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: If I remember correctly Meteor doesn't require any prerequisite node / npm etc to be installed. Maybe they're conflicting? Try to remove them and then check if meteor works.

Comment: The error states there is no tmp file present, which was probably built earlier when starting the app. Make sure you're running with sudo to ensure full permissions to create tmp directories. If that works, look at your permissions in the dir.

Comment: @blueren: First I tried it with meteor installer and after this I installed node.js. I always got the same errormessage.

Comment: @Dandy: Now I have tried it with "sudo meteor" in the right  directory  and the same error message is shown.

The error is thrown here (promise_server.js)

`// Invoke method with args against object in a try-catch block,
// re-throwing any exceptions in the next tick of the event loop, so that
// they won't get captured/swallowed by the caller.
function tryCatchNextTick(object, method, args) {
  try {
    return method.apply(object, args);
  } catch (error) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
      throw error;
    });
  }
}`

Comment: One failure was that I had a different meteor version to the project.
Now I deleted meteor and installed the right version but I get following error:

'                                                                              
/home/fabian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.10vjklo++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/ddp/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:116
      throw error;
            ^
Error: EACCES, open '/home/fabian/.meteorsession'
'

Comment: That looks like a permission error. When you ran "sudo meteor" you probably messed up your permissions. You can fix it with chown -R myuser.myuser .meteor where myuser is your login id